# import class from another directory

Tags: python, import, python-import

I have:

```
script1.py in database/table_inserts/  #trying to import below file into
dbcrud.py in database/                 #trying to import by above file
```

in `script1.py` I have:

```
from ..dbcrud import set_db_setting
```

**but this throws error:**

```
   from ..dbcrud import set_db_setting
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` in the database directory?  If so, I think you can do `from database import dbcrud`.

Comment: No, i do not have one, what should it contain?

Comment: I made a blank __init__.py in database/ , but that doesnt change anything

Comment: @Jshee you need another one in the sub folder too, otherwise it won't be recognized as a package

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative imports in Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)

Comment: @MadPhysicist - sadly, after putting it in `database/` and `database/table_inserts` it still wont let me import `dbcrud.py` into `script1.py` via `from dbcrud import function`

Comment: `from ..dbcrud import function` is still the right way. The double dot is crucial

Answer (score 7):

**Edit:**

Thanks to `@Mad Physicist` comments.

The most easy and trivial way to solve your question is to add an empty `__init__.py` file in `database/` folder and another empty `__init__.py` file to `database/table_inserts/` folder in order to be recognized as a package.

See this example of hierarchy:

```
database/
├── dbcrud.py
├── __init__.py
└── table_inserts
    ├── __init__.py
    └── script1.py

1 directory, 4 files
```

Then all you have to do in `script1.py` is to import your module from `dbcrud.py` like this example:

```
# Note here the double dots '..'
from ..dbcrud import you_module
```

Otherwise, if you want another solution, you can edit your `$PYTHONPATH` variable like this way:

**dbcrud.py:**

```
class DBCrud:
    def __init__(self):
        print("I'm DBCrud'")
```

**script1.py**

```
# Add the parent directory to your module
# by using this kind of hack
import os, sys
sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(sys.path[0], '..'))
# Then import your module
from dbcrud import DBCrud

class Script1:
    def __init__(self):
        print("I'm Script1'")
        DBCrud.__init__(self)

# test
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Script1()
```

Now, from `database/` folder or `database/table_insers/` folder you can run the test example:

```
~$ pwd
/user/path/database/table_inserts
~$ python3 script1.py
```

Output:

```
I'm Script1'
I'm DBCrud'
```

And:

```
~$ pwd
/user/path/database
~$ python3 table_inserts/script1.py
```

Output:

```
I'm Script1'
I'm DBCrud'
```

Comment: Thanks for this lengthy post. I just feel like it should be easier?

Comment: Yes, it's easy, you need just to add `sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(sys.path[0], '..'))` to your `script1.py` then import your module there. If you can't do it right, follow my example and everything will be right.

Comment: @Jshee. Ignore 99% of this answer. Just add a second init in database/table_inserts

Comment: @MadPhysicist does my answer is false ? Could you explain more please ?

Comment: You are doing way too much for a simple problem. If your packages are set up properly, you should never need to edit sys.path.

Comment: specifically, op's import method (from ..dbcrud import...)  would work if the sub-package had an init file

Comment: Thanks again for your comment. I've edite my answer.